# remove GAC assembly using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, assemblies, gac

Like the title says, how can I remove GAC assembly file using vbscript?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this to uninstall it from GAC:

```
gacutil /u YourAssembly
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember gacutil in a .NET enabled shell.

```
C:\>gacutil
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.21022.8
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Usage: Gacutil <command> [ <options> ]
Commands:
  /i <assembly_path> [ /r <...> ] [ /f ]
    Installs an assembly to the global assembly cache.

  /il <assembly_path_list_file> [ /r <...> ] [ /f ]
    Installs one or more assemblies to the global assembly cache.

  /u <assembly_display_name> [ /r <...> ]
    Uninstalls an assembly from the global assembly cache.

  /ul <assembly_display_name_list_file> [ /r <...> ]
    Uninstalls one or more assemblies from the global assembly cache.

  /l [ <assembly_name> ]
    List the global assembly cache filtered by <assembly_name>

  /lr [ <assembly_name> ]
    List the global assembly cache with all traced references.

  /cdl
    Deletes the contents of the download cache

  /ldl
    Lists the contents of the download cache

  /?
    Displays a detailed help screen

 Options:
  /r <reference_scheme> <reference_id> <description>
    Specifies a traced reference to install (/i, /il) or uninstall (/u, /ul).

  /f
    Forces reinstall of an assembly.

  /nologo
    Suppresses display of the logo banner

  /silent
    Suppresses display of all output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSH with VBScript, and open the file using WSH.

http://www.mhuffman.com/notes/language/vbs_intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can call the `gacutil` tool from VBScript:

```
Const GACUTILPATH = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe"
strAssembly = "MyAssembly"  '' or "MyAssembly,Version=1.1.0.0,Culture=en,PublicKeyToken=874e23ab874e23ab"

Set oShell  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run """" & GACUTILPATH & """ /nologo /u " & strAssembly
```